# How to add a Nil object to an Array of objects in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I am looking for a solution to add a nil object to and existing Mappable Model so I can use it for my Placeholder.

here is the model:

```
class PortfolioModel : Mappable {
    
    var photoUrl : String?
    var portfolioId : Int!
    
    required init?(map: Map) {
        
    }
    
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        photoUrl <- map["photoUrl"]
        portfolioId <- map["portfolioId"]
    }
}
```

in another class in my ViewController I have this:

```
var portfolioList : [PortfolioModel]?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can mark the list item as `optional` to be able to add `nil` item to it.

```
var portfolioList : [PortfolioModel?]?
```

Comment: did that already, still won't work, "self.photographerPortfolioURLList.append(nil)" this is the code I am using.

Comment: What is `photographerPortfolioURLList`?

Comment: its an array of [PortfolioModel]

Comment: is it `[PortfolioModel?]` or `[PortfolioModel]`

Comment: its [PortfolioModel?]? as you said above. I've handled it in a different way tho, I have added the String URLs inside of an Array of String and did the thing.

Comment: What is the error? In a normal way if you have `var portfolioList : [PortfolioModel?]?`you should use like `portfolioList?.append(nil)`